# How can I update vehicle's route in veins2.1?

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

I'm building an ITS application using OMNET++, veins and SUMO and i'm trying to
update the vehicle's route with a different route. however both of the two commands (`commandRouteChange`, `commandNewRoute`) that I found in veins did not work.

I compute a new route, and the output is such like this: `std::string newRoute = "AtoB BtoC CtoD DtoE";` then I tried to set this `newRoute` to the vehicle:

`traci->getManager()->commandNewRoute(vehicleID, newRoute);`

then I got the following error: `Error in module (ITS) VANET.host[0].appl (id=9) at event #127412, t=12: Model error: TraCI server reported error executing command 0xc4 ("Can not retrieve road with ID AtoB BtoC CtoD DtoE ").`

I was search and I saw that the `commandNewRoute` and `commandChangeRoute` receives just a single edge as parameter. But I wanna set a full route to a vehicle. Does anyone knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veins 2.1 only implements commands for changing a vehicle's route by modifying its target road ([Command 0xc4 0x31](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State#change_target_.280x31.29)) or by modifying its perception of travel times ([Command 0xc4 0x58](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State#change_edge_travel_time_information_.280x58.29)).

Newer versions of Veins also implement a command for setting arbitrary routes ([Command 0xc4 0x57](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State#change_route_.280x57.29)), which is what you are asking for.

I recommend switching to [Veins 4.3](http://veins.car2x.org/download/), which works with the most recent version of SUMO and gives you a number of improved and more feature-rich simulation models of other components as well. If you cannot upgrade Veins, implementing the desired command should be straightforward as well.